# Eloquent Laravel where with now

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How can I transform this query to eloquent or dbquery in laravel?

```
SELECT
  fases.*,
  processos.processonome 
FROM
  fases
INNER JOIN 
  processos ON processos.processoid = fases.processo_id 
WHERE
  fases.arquivada = 0 
  AND DATEDIFF( fases.avisodata, NOW() ) <= fases.avisodias
```

ARCHIVED RESULT WITH

```
 DB::table('fases')
                ->join('processos', 'fases.processo_id', '=', 'processos.processoid')
                ->where('fases.arquivada', 0)
                ->whereRaw('DATEDIFF(avisodata, NOW()) <= avisodias')
                ->select('fases.*', 'processos.processonome')
                ->get();
```

Comment: Please also explain what you have tried so far and what did not work about this

Comment: I hate to rtfm, but you should really read the excellent documentation of laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will work

```
DB::table('fases')            
        ->join('processos', 'fases.processo_id', '=', 'processos.processoid')
        ->where('fases.arquivada', 0)
        ->where(DB::raw('DATEDIFF( fases.avisodata, NOW() )'), '<=', 'fases.avisodias')
        ->select('fases.*', 'processos.processonome')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks! Had change a litte! in the RAW line to work. But your awnser is 99% corrrect! TY. Will post bellow in "code" mode!